# On Error GoTo : How to avoid goto if no error

Tags: vb.net, exception

I am using **VB.Net** for developing an Application, at certain point it stuck while using `On Error GoTo` the label associated with `On Error GoTo` will executed all time even when their is no error in the block. Here the snippet is:

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim rnd As Random = New Random
        On Error GoTo label
        Dim n, array(10) As Integer
        For i As Integer = 10 To 0 Step -2
            n = rnd.Next(9)
            array(i) = 10 / n
        Next
label:  MsgBox("Exception Occur")
    End Sub
```

My aim is to display error message as **Exception Occur** when any error occur while execution.But it prints all the times. can anyone suggest one solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Label` is always executed since it is the next line to be executed after the `For`, their is nothing in your code to break this normal flow, so you need to include `Exit Eub` before `label` to prevent this. ie, the code will be:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim rnd As Random = New Random
    On Error GoTo label
    Dim n, array(10) As Integer
    For i As Integer = 10 To 0 Step -2
        n = rnd.Next(9)
        array(i) = 10 / n
    Next
    Exit Sub
 label:  MsgBox("exception")
End Sub
```

While using this `Exit Sub` will became the next line to be executed after the `For`. so it will help you to comes out from the `Sub`

Comment: While this answers the question, the use of `On Error GoTo` should be strongly discouraged in VB.Net in favor of `Try Catch`

Answer (score 5):

Try to avoid any `On Error GoTo` statement anywhere in your code. It could cause a lot of troubles and it is simply a bad practice, and it does not look good.([Spaghetti code)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code) Instead, you can use a simple [Try...Catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx) statement. Here is a short example:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   Dim rnd As Random = New Random
   Try
     Dim n, array(10) As Integer
     For i As Integer = 10 To 0 Step -2
       n = rnd.Next(9)
       array(i) = 10 / n
     Next
  Catch ex as Exception
     MsgBox("Exception Occur")
  End try
End Sub
```